# What doesn't my wordpress template show the_content after updating wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to fix an old wordpress site from 2009. I can't seem to make the content show for pages.

I'm not sure if it's because I upgraded wordpress or not.

Any ideas? The title and other tags are showing fine.

```html
<div id="contentleft">

  <div class="postarea">

    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/breadcrumb.php");?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h1>

    <div class="date">

      <div class="dateleft">
        <p><span class="time"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span> by
          <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;
          <?php edit_post_link('(Edit)', '', ''); ?> <br /> 
          Filed under <?php the_category(', ') ?>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="dateright">
      </div>

    </div>

    <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="postmeta">
      <p><span class="tags">Tags: <?php the_tags('') ?></span></p>
    </div>

    <!--
   <?php trackback_rdf(); ?>
   -->

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>
      <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After exploring this, the problem is with old plugins. Hopefully that helps someone in the future.